# Hit bundle size limit when deploying Operator with OLM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk, operator-lifecycle-manager

When deploying my operator bundle using OLM I get the following error:

```
level=error msg="File with size ... exceeded 1048576 limit, aborting" file=/bundle/manifests/crd.yaml
Error: error loading manifests from directory: file crd.yaml bigger than total allowed limit
Usage:
  opm alpha bundle extract [flags]
```

Where does this size limit come from and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundles have a size limitation because their manifests are used to create a configMap, and the Kubernetes API does not allow configMaps larger than `~1MB`. Beginning with OLM version `v0.19.0` and OPM `1.17.5`, these values are now compressed using `Gzip` and then encoded using `Base64` to accommodate larger bundles. The recommendation is to upgrade the SDK and OLM versions used.